# chrome-gnome-shell causing crash?

Tags: linux, shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I am not sure if this has been answered as I am not really sure of the problem. At least once (sometimes more) during the day I get a notice that Ubuntu crashed. The info says it's related to the `chrome-gnome-shell`(I have reinstalled `chrome-gnome-shell`). I also can't get my local Gnome extensions to list at: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. Using the `browser console` in Firefox, I get the following when I bring up that page:

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.  ExtensionCommon.jsm:265
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell: 
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell: (process:13043): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_release: assertion 'application->priv->use_count > 0' failed
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell: [13043] Uncaught exception of type <class 'gi._glib.GError'> occured
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell:   File "/usr/bin/chrome-gnome-shell", line 550, in <module>
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell:     app = ChromeGNOMEShell('--gapplication-service' in sys.argv)
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell:   File "/usr/bin/chrome-gnome-shell", line 67, in __init__
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell:     self.register()
stderr output from native app org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell: [13043] Exception: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome (v3.8.4), Linux kernel 4.4.0-71, Firefox 52.0.2 32-bit.

Any ideas of what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old chrome-gnome-shell version.
Just upgrade.

Comment: I'm using version `8.2-0ubuntu1`, which is the latest.

Comment: I installed `8-2ubuntu4~ubuntu14.04.2`, which my Synaptic Pkg Mgr says is a downgrade but it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.